# AWS Cognito annd Google Attribute Mapping suddenly doesn't work anymore

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, google-signin

My application uses Cognito and Google as a social auth provider. Everything works fine except that email attribute is not mapped anymore.
It was working before on my development AWS account, and now I deployed it on another account which is our production AWS account. Everything is deployed via CloudFormation so human error is limited.

Signup via Google works fine, the only thing is that the email attribute is not mapped anymore. I tried with the same google oauth keys so the problem does not comes from the Google configuration side. I still request email, profile and openid scopes, both in my client app and Cognito settings, and Google email attribute is mapped in Cognito config.

After a user signed up, I can see him in the Cognito Console, mapped to its Google account, but the email attribute is not set. I am stuck for 2 days now, I compared all Cognito settings with the development AWS account and it is all exactly the same, I don't know what else to do.

Any help would be very appreciated.

[image: Attribute mapping]

[image: created user]

[image: cognito scopes]

[image: amplify scopes]

Thanks

Comment: Please check with jwt to see data and we can go from there.

Comment: how did you solve this? how do you handle new cognito pool users named google_123123123123?

Comment: @milan I did not solve it yet. I am going to work on it next week and see if I can understand the problem now.

Comment: @milan 4 months later I solved it: the email attribute was not Writable in the app client settings

Comment: nice! think i saw that was the problem somewhere in the forums... what happens when someone signs in thru google, are there any new cognito user records or no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally solved it: the email attribute was not writable in the app client settings.